# How to use generated variable with alert function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

This is the code that I create for my app in order to provide some error messages:

```
function createTimer(): void {
    if (!timer.start) {
    Alert.alert(strings.reminders['date-required'])
    return;
} else if (!timer.end) {
    Alert.alert(strings.reminders['date-required'])
    return;
}
let curTimer = timer;
curTimer.task = currentTask
setCreateLoading(true)
timerService.create(curTimer).then(() => {
    setCreateLoading(false);
    Alert.alert(strings.alert.success, '', [
        { text: strings.button.ok, onPress: () => closeNewTimerModal() }
    ],
    { cancelable: false }
    )     
    }).catch(e => {
    let message: string;

    if(e.code == Error.TIMER_INTERVALS_INTERSECT) {
        message = strings['time-tracking']['time-intervals-intersect']
    }
    else if(e.code == Error.START_DATE_IS_AFTER_END_DATE) {
    message = strings['time-tracking']['start-after-end']
    }
    else if(e.code == Error.END_DATE_IS_AFTER_NOW) {
    message = strings['time-tracking']['end-after-now']
    }
    else if(e.code == Error.TASK_IS_ARCHIVED) {
    message = strings['time-tracking']['task-archived']
    }

    Alert.alert(*)
    setCreateLoading(false);
})
```

But I cannot use the message parameter in the `alert` function.

What should I write where the star is? I think it should be:

```
Alert.alert(strings.message.something)
```

but I can't find the `something`. When I write just `Alert.alert(strings.message)` the popup opens, but there is no error.

Comment: Please refer to the React Native docs to see how to use Alert.alert()

To help you debug this, just before the last Alert, can you please console.log(message) and paste your result

  [1]: https://reactnative.dev/docs/alert

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but if I may suggest, you could use sweet alert for easy alerting system. sweet alert also have the tutorial to customize your alert window. hope it helps.